# Em R, o que é uma tibble?

Tags: r, data.frame, tibble

O que é uma `tibble`? Como ela difere de um `data.frame`?

O código abaixo cria um [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame).

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- base::data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  texto = letters[1:10],
  numero = rnorm(10)
)

df
#>    id texto      numero
#> 1   1     a -0.56047565
#> 2   2     b -0.23017749
#> 3   3     c  1.55870831
#> 4   4     d  0.07050839
#> 5   5     e  0.12928774
#> 6   6     f  1.71506499
#> 7   7     g  0.46091621
#> 8   8     h -1.26506123
#> 9   9     i -0.68685285
#> 10 10     j -0.44566197
class(df)
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

E esse uma [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble) com os mesmos dados.

```r
set.seed(123)
tbl <- tibble::tibble(
  id = 1:10,
  texto = letters[1:10],
  numero = rnorm(10)
)

tbl
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>       id texto  numero
#>    <int> <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1     1 a     -0.560 
#>  2     2 b     -0.230 
#>  3     3 c      1.56  
#>  4     4 d      0.0705
#>  5     5 e      0.129 
#>  6     6 f      1.72  
#>  7     7 g      0.461 
#>  8     8 h     -1.27  
#>  9     9 i     -0.687 
#> 10    10 j     -0.446
class(tbl)
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Além do pretty print a tibble carrega em si agrupamentos, como os criados pelo group_by ou rowise(), além disso a tibble support de uma forma bem elegante df e tibbles dentro dela mesma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De uma forma mais extensa

1. Tibbles dentro de tibbles
2. Coverção automática para suportar os agrupamentos do tidyverse
3. Pretty Print
4. Multi-Dispatch as funções do data.frame funcionam no tibble

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Tibbles inside tibbles 

df_a <- data.frame(a = c(1,2),b = c("a","b"))
df_b <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3),b = c("a","b","c"),c = c(3,4,5))

# Error
# df_c <- data.frame(a = list(df_a),b = list(df_b))


tb_a <- tibble(a = c(1,2),b = c("a","b"))
tb_b <- tibble(a = c(1,2,3),b = c("a","b","c"),c = c(3,4,5))

tb_c <- tibble(a = list(tb_a),b = list(tb_b))

tb_c
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   a                b               
#>   <list>           <list>          
#> 1 <tibble [2 x 2]> <tibble [3 x 3]>


# Conversion into tibble

df_a %>% 
  group_by(a)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Groups:   a [2]
#>       a b    
#>   <dbl> <fct>
#> 1     1 a    
#> 2     2 b

df_a %>% 
  rowwise(b)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Rowwise:  b
#>       a b    
#>   <dbl> <fct>
#> 1     1 a    
#> 2     2 b


# Pretty print, default more than 20 rows to 10

df_a <- data.frame(a = rep(1,21))

df_a
#>    a
#> 1  1
#> 2  1
#> 3  1
#> 4  1
#> 5  1
#> 6  1
#> 7  1
#> 8  1
#> 9  1
#> 10 1
#> 11 1
#> 12 1
#> 13 1
#> 14 1
#> 15 1
#> 16 1
#> 17 1
#> 18 1
#> 19 1
#> 20 1
#> 21 1


tibble(df_a)
#> # A tibble: 21 x 1
#>        a
#>    <dbl>
#>  1     1
#>  2     1
#>  3     1
#>  4     1
#>  5     1
#>  6     1
#>  7     1
#>  8     1
#>  9     1
#> 10     1
#> # ... with 11 more rows



# See multi-dispatch, a tibble is also a data.frame

class(df_a)
#> [1] "data.frame"

class(tb_a)
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
class(df_a)
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Um objeto **tibble** não é **data.frame** e nem **data.frame** é **tibble**. Isso é um equívoco dizer, visto que tratam-se de estruturas de dados distintas, mas que para o usuário final e ao código final poderá não ter grandes diferenças. O que quero dizer é que basicamente o que você conhece de **data.frame** você poderá usar em objetos da classe `tbl_df`. Perceba que R é uma linguagem Orientada à Objeto - OO e a implementação das classes `tbl_df` herdam as classes `tbl`e `data.frame`.

```r
> library(tibble)
> as_tibble(iris)
# A tibble: 150 x 5
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# … with 140 more rows
> class(as_tibble(iris))
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Um dos objetivos da **tibble** é ser uma estrutura de quadro mais organizadas que às implementadas em classes mais antigas de R, como é o caso da `data.frame`. Por exemplo, na **tibble** você não atribui nomes para as linhas. Veja também que uma **tibble** se adequa ao tamanho do seu prompt de comando e imprime apenas as primeiras linhas do conjunto de dados, o que seria muito ruim se não fosse assim, caso seu conjunto de dados tivesse diversas entradas. Além disso, observando uma **tibble** você entende bem qual a estrutura de dados e/ou tipo de dados de suas variáveis. Essas são as principais diferenças.

Answer (score 1):

"Tibble são data.frames, mas eles ajustam alguns comportamentos antigos para tornar a vida um pouco mais fácil". O R é uma linguagem antiga, e algumas coisas que eram úteis há 10 ou 20 anos agora estão atrapalhando (Grolemund & Wickham).

O livro R for Data Science informa que há duas diferenças entre o Tibble e o data.frame: *printing* e *subsetting*.

Além disso, "tibble são projetados para que você não sobrecarregue acidentalmente seu console ao imprimir grandes bancos de dados".

Fonte: R for Data Science https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html

Referência [Tibbles vs. data.frame](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html#tibbles-vs.data.frame)